# PHP - MySQL Check only returning False

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've quickly designed a very simple checking script for PHP to state whether something is Online or Offline.

However regarding of what ID number I set in the MySQL database under the status table, it returns "Offline" all of the time. I have tried Greater Than, Less Than and Equal to.

Return Code

```
                <?php
                    require ('status.php');
                        if ( '$query' = 1 ) {
                        print mysql_error();
                        echo "Radio is Offline";
                        } else {
                        echo "Radio is Online";
                    } 
                ?>
```

Status.php

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "removed";
    $password = "removed";
    $dbname = "removed";
    mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
        connect to database! Please try again later.");
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM status";
?>
```

Table structure is "status"
ID field is an integer type with Length 1, no primary key set.

Comment: Since you've just started, I would suggest starting over and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) :)

Comment: `if ( '$query' = 1 ) {` should be `if ( '$query' == 1 ) {`

Comment: @DevZer0 Better yet, `if ($query == 1)` :)

Comment: more loose the single quote also `$query == 1`

Comment: why not `$query === 1`

Comment: Since we are on the subject it's a good idea to start using Yoda conditionals to help catch assignment vs comparison issues i.e.  `1 === $query`

Comment: @Orangepill Imho, that should really be the task of a proper IDE ;-)

Comment: @Jack What IDEs support this feature? I got hooked on Komodo edit about 5 years ago and I'm about ready for a change

Comment: @Orangepill PhpStorm does it :) it has a whole bunch of inspections it does for you, together with common refactoring tools as well ... it's awzome, albeit paid product :)

Comment: @Jack I'll check it out... I see it's available for linux :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a code review answer, but it should help you nonetheless. First off, you will want to create a function to retrieve the status instead of including code files in this way:

```
function getStatusId($db)
{
    $result = $db->query('SELECT ID FROM status');
    $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    return current($rows); // return first row or false
}
```

This function takes an existing database connection as its input and returns the value of the ID column. To call it:

```
// create database connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=removed', 'removed', 'removed');

// call your function
if (getStatusId($db) == 1) {
    echo 'on';
} else {
    echo 'off';
}
```

See also: [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo)